# Elastic nest query field should exist filter

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using elasticsearch 5.2 with Nest client to query.  I have a working query with date range looks like:

```
var boolQuery = new BoolQueryDescriptor<AttractionDocument>();

//https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2570 must is not additive, we cannot split out query as before it all has to be one big one

boolQuery.Must(
    mn => AddRegionQuery(permissions, mn),
    mn => AddOffersQuery(permissions, mn),
    mn => request.AddDateFilter ? mn.DateRange(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableFrom).LessThanOrEquals(DateTime.Now)) : mn,
    mn => request.AddDateFilter ? mn.DateRange(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableTo).GreaterThanOrEquals(DateTime.Now)) : mn,
    mn => AddGenresQuery(genres, mn)
);
```

The issue I have is AvailableTo is not always populated and hence it will for some documents not exist.

I tried to add the following:

```
if (request.AddDateFilter)
{
    boolQuery.MustNot(mn => mn.Exists(f => f.Field(e => e.AvailableTo)));
}
```

The issue now is query becomes too restrictive.  Ideally the exists part I want as a Should? What I am trying to achieve is only apply date range for AvailableTo if we have that field else ignore and return results without that date.  If I take out the AvailableTo part I do get results.

Comment: Sounds like you need to combine `.Exists()` and `.DateRange()` on `AvailableTo`?

Comment: Any ideas on how to do that? Been experimenting but cannot see how todo it.

Comment: I'll add an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to combine an `exists` query with a `range` query on `AvailableTo` to include documents where the `AvailableTo` field exists and must be satisfy the range condition, and create a disjunction with `AvailableTo` exists query in a `bool` query `must_not` clause i.e. invert the exists.

Something like the following (I've commented out queries that aren't provided)

```
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var request = new 
{
    AddDateFilter = true
};

var boolQuery = new BoolQueryDescriptor<AttractionDocument>();

boolQuery.Must(
    // mn => AddRegionQuery(permissions, mn),
    // mn => AddOffersQuery(permissions, mn),
    mn => request.AddDateFilter ? mn.DateRange(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableFrom).LessThanOrEquals(DateTime.Now)) : mn,
    mn => request.AddDateFilter ? (mn.Exists(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableTo)) &&
                                  mn.DateRange(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableTo).GreaterThanOrEquals(DateTime.Now))) ||
                                  !mn.Exists(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableTo)) : mn //,
    // mn => AddGenresQuery(genres, mn)
);

client.Search<AttractionDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.Bool(b => boolQuery))
);
```

This produces the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "availableFrom": {
              "lte": "2018-11-15T20:18:10.528482+10:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "availableTo"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "availableTo": {
                          "gte": "2018-11-15T20:18:10.5304815+10:00"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "availableTo"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Since the range and exist queries are predicates (a document either matches the condition or it doesn't) as opposed to queries that should calculate relevancy scores, these could be `bool` query `filter` clauses

```
boolQuery.Must(
    // Uncomment below queries, or add (QueryContainer[])null to run
    // mn => AddRegionQuery(permissions, mn),
    // mn => AddOffersQuery(permissions, mn),
    // mn => AddGenresQuery(genres, mn)
).Filter(
    mn => request.AddDateFilter ? mn.DateRange(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableFrom).LessThanOrEquals(DateTime.Now)) : mn,
    mn => request.AddDateFilter ? (+mn.Exists(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableTo)) &&
                                  +mn.DateRange(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableTo).GreaterThanOrEquals(DateTime.Now))) ||
                                  !mn.Exists(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableTo)) : mn    
);

client.Search<AttractionDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.Bool(b => boolQuery))
);
```

which creates the query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "availableFrom": {
              "lte": "2018-11-15T20:22:25.4556963+10:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "availableTo"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "availableTo": {
                          "gte": "2018-11-15T20:22:25.4587138+10:00"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "availableTo"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Operator overloading on queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html) really helps here, to write complex bool queries more succinctly

Comment: Russ, Many thanks for complete solution and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so think I have this sussed. I took out the must date range and made it a should so query now looks like:

```
 var boolQuery = new BoolQueryDescriptor<AttractionDocument>();

        if (request.AddDateFilter)
        {
            boolQuery.Should(mn => mn.DateRange(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableTo).GreaterThanOrEquals(DateTime.Now)));
        }


        //https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2570 must is not additive, we cannot split out query as before it all has to be one big one
        boolQuery.Must(
            mn => AddRegionQuery(permissions, mn),

            mn => AddOffersQuery(permissions, mn),

            mn => request.AddDateFilter ? mn.DateRange(d => d.Field(f => f.AvailableFrom).LessThanOrEquals(DateTime.Now)) : mn,

            mn => AddGenresQuery(genres, mn)
         );
```

I now get back results with in the range for both dates and matches where we dont have an availableTo date set.